# tinyMCE problem with jQuery load

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have a DIV and a Load button on my page and when I click in Load button the jQuery loads a HTML from another file, this HTML file have texteareas and start tinymce.

Ex:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function loadForm() {
    $("#myContent").load("HTMLFile");
}

function goback() {
    $("#myContent").load("Another HTML File Without TINYMCE");
}
</script>

<div id="myContent"></div>
<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="loadForm()"/>
```

HTMLFile:

```
<textarea id="myText" class="tinymce"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="goback()"/>
<script language="Javascript">
$("textarea.tinymce").tinymce({
    // Configurations here
});
</script>
```

The problem: When I click in Load button on my page the tinyMCE works, but after this if I click in Cancel button and after in Load button again the tinyMCE don't load more, only in first time.

Any tips?

Comment: I'd suggest you have a good hard look at what happens to the code after you have loaded in the tinyMCE code.  tinyMCE may modify its container or something along those lines, so use a tool like FireBug to see what's happening and go from there.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find something with firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding the callback function of the load method to initialize the tineMCE editor.

```
 function loadForm() {
    $("#myContent").load("HTMLFile", {}, function(){
        $("textarea.tinymce").tinymce({
            // Configurations here
         });

    });
 }
```

So the HTMLFile will NOT have any script.